# Why doesn't my publicly shared Datadog dashboard show any data

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I created a Datadog dashboard with two widgets that show different formats of the same dataset (same filter used for both). Both widgets work when I'm logged into Datadog, but only one of them displays any data when I use the publicly shared link while the other shows No matching results found

[image: logged in view]

[image: public view]

The widgets are set to use the global date range, which users of the public link can change, so I know the date ranges are properly synchronised across both widgets

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @RishabhSagar - No I didn't, but I stopped investigating as I left that position last year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the datadog docs there's a note under [Share a dashboard by public URL](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/sharing/#share-a-dashboard-by-public-url) saying:

> Note: Widgets based on APM traces queries do not display data on
> public dashboards. The Log Stream widget doesn’t show data either, but
> other log-based queries do.

It could be a reason for your widgets showing empty data.

Comment: I no longer have access to that system, but will mark this as an answer, as it seems entirely reasonable and has come from the docs - Thank you !